# When opening a file, Word slowly counts the pages before it is ready to work

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

When I open a file in Microsoft Word, Word does not open the whole file immediately, but loads one page after another. There is a small counter in the lower right corner of the file window in which the total number of pages slowly counts up (screenshot from the German version of Word):

[screenshot of the page counter from the German version of Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1I81.png)

This is not a problem when I am working on files that are a handful of pages long, although even then it takes about ten seconds to load 50 pages of text, tables, and images, but when, as in this case, the file totals several hundred pages (631 KB of pure text, no tables, no images, no links etc.), it takes about a minute for Word to load the whole file – and while the file loads (and the page counter counts up), I cannot use the file, because whenever Word loads a new bunch of pages, the file window scrolls to a different place.

**How can I avoid this slow loading?**

Hardware: MacBook Air (mid 2012)
System: macOS 10.13.2
Version: Microsoft Word for Mac 15.41

*Please note that I have observed this behavior in all versions of Word since Word for Mac 2011 under all version of Mac OS X since 10.6 and that no other software on my computer opens files so slowly.*

Answer (score 0):

> **How can I avoid this slow loading?**

A solution some people use is to split the MS-Word document into a series of smaller documents at some natural page boundary (chapter, section etc).

As an aside, the solution I use is to use a plain text editor to edit the content and something such as [Markdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) or [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to create final formats such as HTML or MS-Word's DOCX - but you probably have some requirements to use Word.